# ActiveJob Rspec Test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, rails-activejob

I have the following Rspec test for an ActiveJob:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ProofreadDocumentReportJob, type: :job do

  before do 
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
  end


  subject(:job) { described_class.perform_later(create(:report)) }

  it 'queues the job' do
    expect { job }
      .to have_enqueued_job
  end
end
```

This tests fails with the following message:

```
expected to enqueue exactly 1 jobs, but enqueued 2
```

However if I do write my tests as follows not using the subject job it passes:

```
  it 'queues the job' do
    expect { ProofreadDocumentReportJob.perform_later }
      .to have_enqueued_job
  end
```

Why does using the subject job not work?

Answer (score 0):

an oldie but hey I ended up here in and google brought be here for:
`expected to enqueue exactly 1 jobs, but enqueued 2`

- which below answers.

```rb
      expect do
        subject.run
      end.to have_enqueued_job(DeliverWebhookJob).on_queue('webhooks').at_least(:twice)
    end
```

Now onto OP:

- `report` factory it seems is implementing 2 jobs / that would be my attack vector to solving this quite old of questions.. and [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623266/chell) is most likely a `ruby` god by now..